# Unable to get the return type in a Parser match the signature in Haskell using the do syntax

Tags: parsing, haskell

I am learning Haskell and working through **Graham Hutton's - Programming in Haskell**. For a week I am now stuck in the chapter on **Functional Parsers**. I am following the examples as they are and can't get the types match for this one parser using the do syntax. Following is the code:

```
type Parser a = String -> [(a,String)]

ret :: a -> Parser a
ret v = \inp -> [(v , inp)]

failure :: Parser a
failure = \inp -> []

item :: Parser Char
item = \inp -> case inp of
                 [] -> []
                 (x:xs) -> [(x,xs)]

parse :: Parser a -> String -> [(a, String)]
parse p inp = p inp

p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = do 
    x <- item
    item
    y <- item
    ret (x, y)
```

Loading this script into GHCi throws an error complaining about the types not matching for the last parser **"p"**. I actually agree with the error because **"item"** parser has a return type of `[(Char, String)]`. Therefore the return type for parser **p** is `[(([(Char, String)], [(Char, String)]), String)]` but parser p is declared to be of type `Parser (Char , Char)` which translates to `[((Char, Char), String)]`. This is the problem I am facing.

To get around it I worte myself a new function as follows:

```
getIt :: [(a,b)] -> a
getIt = \(x:xs) -> fst x
```

and modified the Parser p as follows:

```
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = do 
    x <- item
    item
    y <- item
    ret (getIt x, getIt y)
```

This change lines up my return types but the output is still not right:

```
Prelude> parse p "abcdef"
[(('a','c'), "def")] --Expected output according to the book
[(('a','a'), "abcdef")] --Output I get after my changes
```

Any help is really appreciated. I will update the post if I find something myself.

Thanks

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28200987/why-am-i-getting-a-type-error-in-this-sequence-of-parsers-lecture-8-by-erik-mei

Answer (score 1):

Remember that you can't quite use `do`-notation yet as proper usage of the `do` notation requires you to have a `Monad` instance for `newtype Parser`. Since you are using a type synonym, the compiler is happily using the `Monad` instance for the `(->) r` type – which is not what you want! In an ideal world the compiler would have been able to read your intent and complained, but sadly it could not.

Sequencing your parser type is more complicated than sequencing the arrow type. The arrow type doesn't know that we mean `[]` to be failure or that we want each parser to gobble up a little and then spit out what's left. So let's define a sequencing operator like `>>>=` that encodes our ideas:

```hs
(>>>=) :: Parser a -> (a -> Parser b) -> Parser b
p >>>= f = \input -> case parse p input of
                     []         -> []
                     [(v, out)] -> parse (f v) out
```

Then let's desugar your `do` block using this operator:

```hs
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = item >>>= \x ->
    item >>>= \_ ->
    item >>>= \y ->
    ret (x, y)
```

And that should make it typecheck. `parse p "abcdef" => [(('a','c'),"def")]`.

Credit for this code goes to [Ionuț G. Stan](https://github.com/igstan/programming-in-haskell/blob/master/functional-parsers.hs).

### Alternatively

Alternatively we can skip ahead a little and implement the `Monad` instance. We insist on doing it so that we can keep our nice `do`-block. The first order of business is to use `newtype` so we can attach typeclass instances to our type.

```hs
newtype Parser a =
  Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }
```

For a type to have `Monad`, it must first have `Functor` and `Applicative`. Functor is easy enough to discharge with `deriving (Functor)`.  Applicative is a little trickier, but very similar to the `>>>=` we wrote above.

```hs
newtype Parser a =
  Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }
  deriving (Functor)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x =
    Parser (\inp -> [(x, inp)])
  left <*> right =
    Parser (\inp -> case parse left inp of
              [] -> []
              [(a2b, s)] -> case parse right s of
                [] -> []
                [(a, out)] -> [(a2b a, out)])
```

Implementing `Monad` is a breeze as it mostly involves copying and pasting our `>>>=` definition into the definition for the actual name of the operator, `>>=`:

```hs
instance Monad Parser where
  return =
    pure
  p >>= a2q =
    Parser (\inp -> case parse p inp of
              [] -> []
              [(a, out)] -> parse (a2q a) out)
```

Restoring your code back to full:

```hs
p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = do
  x <- item
  item
  y <- item
  return (x, y)
```

`parse p "abcdef" => [(('a','c'),"def")]`, as desired.

### Alternatively alternatively

We could actually elide the `Monad` instance entirely. Note that the parser can be written with just the applicative methods:

```hs
q :: Parser (Char, Char)
q = (,) <$> (item <* item <*> item)
```

You can read this (very abstruse) code as "using the `(,)` function to collect all the items we are about to take, take one item and keep it, take one more item and throw it away, and then take one more item."

This is likely more information than required, but I'm a big fan of applicative. It deserves more spotlight! Popular parsing packages like `parsec` or `attoparsec` encourage the use of applicative parsers for reasons of performance.

One wonders if our `do`-block would continue to work once we delete our lovely `Monad` instance. Not as of yet! But a [future GHC will have ApplicativeDo](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ApplicativeDo).

### Full code

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

module Main where

newtype Parser a =
  Parser { parse :: String -> [(a, String)] }
  deriving (Functor)

instance Applicative Parser where
  pure x =
    Parser (\inp -> [(x, inp)])
  left <*> right =
    Parser (\inp -> case parse left inp of
              [] -> []
              [(a2b, s)] -> case parse right s of
                [] -> []
                [(a, out)] -> [(a2b a, out)])

instance Monad Parser where
  return =
    pure
  p >>= a2q =
    Parser (\inp -> case parse p inp of
              [] -> []
              [(a, out)] -> parse (a2q a) out)

failure :: Parser a
failure = Parser (\inp -> [])

item :: Parser Char
item = Parser (\inp -> case inp of
                 [] -> []
                 (x:xs) -> [(x, xs)])

p :: Parser (Char, Char)
p = do
  x <- item
  item
  y <- item
  return (x, y)
```